# Access all values of an "underlying" key in a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have already searched around but haven't quite found an answer to my problem, if I have missed something please point me to the correct search terms! :)

**I have this dictionary:**

[image: Dictionary]

The data is read in with `json.loads()`.

How can I access all values of one key e.g. "username" for all "users".

With `print(x["users"][0]["id"])` I am able to get the value for one specific key, or with `print(x["users"])` all values for all users (e.g. all entries unter 0,1,2, etc), but I haven't managed to access all values for an underlying layer of a nested dict.

Comment: Use a loop to process all the users.

Comment: You practically wrote the code in your description: `"username" for all "users"` -- just how are you stuck in writing the corresponding code for that?  Your blocking point seems to be that you expect to get that result *without* iteration (i.e. `for`).

Comment: Off-site links and [images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure what exactly do you want to do with that info, but you could do the following in the case of simple print:

```
for elem in x[“users”]:
    print(elem[“id”])
```

You can generalize that to any task you want to do on individual user inside users.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension.

```
all_usernames = [u['username'] for u in x]
```